# I want to restrict access for my azure Kubernetes nginx ingress controller from a particular IP address but only for a particular path (location)

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks, nginx-ingress

I want to restrict access for my azure Kubernetes nginx ingress controller from a particular IP address but only for a particular path (location).

I want to apply the restriction only to one path not to the others, is there any configuration snippet or server snippet that can help to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/whitelist-source-range` may helps

Reference: https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/main/docs/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations.md#whitelist-source-range

### Edit

Also, we can split the ingress into 2 to separate the restriction. I hope this meet your requirement

Example

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress-restricted
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/whitelist-source-range: "1.2.3.4/32" # Replace with your desired IP address
spec:
  rules:
    - host: example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /restricted-path
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: my-service
                port:
                  number: 80
```

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress-root
spec:
  rules:
    - host: example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: my-service
                port:
                  number: 80
```

Comment: Hi Jutin, the above example applies to all the backend paths I want to apply only to a particular path

Comment: We can split the ingress to root and with path and apply different annotation. Let see if this meet your requirement